# Merging branches With Git

Tags: git

I am using git for windows to manage a local project. I have two branches, 'master' and 'change_specific'. I have added some extra files to 'change_specific'. Those files don't show up when I switch to 'master'. When I call

```
git merge -m "don't need old branch" master change_specific
```

git tells me "Already up-to-date. Yeeah!". Yet the branches seem to have different files. I would like to delete 'change_specific' and be done with it, yet I am afraid that will wipe out my added files - a bad thing. It seems there is something I missed when I scanned the git documentation. **What is going on and what should I do?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# git checkout master
# git merge change_specific
```

That should do it. `git merge <branch1> <branch2>` actually tries to merge *three* branches, the two you gave on the command line and the current branch. If two of them are actually the same it might explain the “Already up-to-date” message.

If you haven’t exposed your changes to the world yet I’d rather perform a rebase:

```
# git checkout change_specific
# git rebase master
# git checkout master
# git merge change_specific
```

This will apply the changes from the “change`_`specific” branch to the current master, rewriting the history linearly. After this you can safely delete the “change_specific” branch with `git branch -d change_specific`.